# XMLHttpRequest responseText initial value

Tags: javascript, mysql, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I'm trying to understand someone else's code to fix some bugs. At one point a call to xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); is made in a JavaScript function, and the value for the responseText property is already set (checked with console.log(xmlhttp) right after the call). That value is meaningful (some values from a MySQL DB) but they are wrong (wrong column) and I want to change them.

How come it has values right after instantiating the object? What kind of call should I look for to find where those values are set?

P.D.: I'm fairly new to JS and I'm a bit lost in the woods.

edit:

I was able to track the behaviour further:

```
todbajax=ajaxObject(); // here is the xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
todbajax.open("POST", "install/dataset.php", true );
todbajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
    console.log("1", todbajax.responseText);
    if (todbajax.readyState==4) {
        console.log("2", todbajax.responseText);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

The console output is as follows:

```
 1
 1      ["view","test2","test","asdfadsf"]
 2      ["view","test2","test","asdfadsf"]
```

Comment: Please provide some more context (as in more code). I suspect that there is an asynchronous function callback which you misinterpret as beeing "right after the call".

Comment: I solved it. It seems that console.log(request) waits for everything to end, then prints, while console.log(request.responseText) prints right away. The object was being filled elsewere in the code, (in the dataset.php file).

Answer (score 0):

What is the value that you are getting from responseText? When I execute the following line of code you get an empty string back. So between instantiating and printing the value something must happen.

```
console.log(new XMLHttpRequest().responseText); // => ""
```

Comment: If i do
`console.log(xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest().responseText);` I get an empty string.
but if I do `console.log(xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest());` the responseText field has data.

Comment: Returns an empty string by default. 

    console.log((xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()).responseText);

Comment: @Yeyo, I just did that myself, and there is no data within.  So whatever is happening, it has to do with your code.  What is the code of your ajaxObject function?